# Replace after string occurrence in text file

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to replace anything after 'databaseDir=' in a config file:

```
# Config file example
homeDir=c:\Application\home
databaseDir=C:\OldApplication\home

(Get-Content -Path $configFile) -replace "databaseDir=*", "databaseDir=C:\Application\home"
```

This is not working. I thought `*` matched any character after `databaseDir=`
How can I fix this?

Comment: the `-replace` operator is a _regex_ operator. so `*` means `zero or more of the preceding char`.  what you likely want is to replace that with `.+` which means `one or more of any character`.

Comment: you can use [\S]* to match Non-whitespace characters